# If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3,$ prove $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+c+6}}\le \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math

> **Problem.** If $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=3,$ prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+b+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+c+6}}\le \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}.$$

I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but this way leads to reverse inequality.

Indeed, $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b+6}}=\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{a+b+6}})\le (a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b+6}.$$It implies to prove $$\frac{1}{a+b+6}+\frac{1}{c+b+6}+\frac{1}{a+c+6}\le \frac{9}{8(a+b+c)}.$$ But by Cauchy-Schwarz again,$$\frac{1}{a+b+6}+\frac{1}{c+b+6}+\frac{1}{a+c+6}\ge\frac{9}{2(a+b+c)+18} \ge \frac{9}{8(a+b+c)}.$$
I hope to see some ideas. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: No one knows (so far).

Comment: Square roots are evoking  Jensen's inequality

Comment: @TATAbox btw the trouble of reverse inequality was caused because you applied C-S incorrectly. We have $=\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{a+b+6}})\le \color{green}{\sqrt{(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b+6}}}$ (note the square root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**.

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{8a}{a + b + 6}}\right)^2
\le \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8a}{a + 1/2}\right)\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + 1/2}{a + b + 6}\right). \tag{1}$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8a}{a + 1/2}\right)\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + 1/2}{a + b + 6}\right) \le 9. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true which is verified by Mathematica.

Comment: (+1) Nice applying C-B-S ! The yield $a+\dfrac{1}{2}$ is only appropriate one, right ?

Comment: @TATAbox I don't know.

Comment: I think we can use $BW$ to solve the last inequality.

Comment: @TATAbox Perhaps it is complicated by hand.

Comment: Is eligible to accept the anwser? I think it pasted 5 days.

Comment: @TATAbox You feel free to do it. If there is a much better solution, you can change the acceptance.

Comment: @TATAbox, you should expand all and use BW method